# Apache2 Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, xubuntu

I deployed Ruby on Rails on Apache2 (How To : http://www.modrails.com/videos/passenger.mov)

and after I restart the apache, the error comes out

`[Wed Oct 21 00:45:48.781816 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10994] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Wed Oct 21 00:45:48.781905 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10994] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Wed Oct 21 00:45:48.781931 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10994] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Wed Oct 21 00:45:48.781945 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10994] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Wed Oct 21 00:45:48.781967 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10994] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Wed Oct 21 00:45:48.785039 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10994:tid 3074509440] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Wed Oct 21 00:45:48.785239 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10994:tid 3074509440] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Wed Oct 21 00:45:48.785261 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10994:tid 3074509440] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}`

I had watched [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/558283/apache2-config-variable-is-not-defined) and not worked..
(the OS is Xubuntu)