# undefined variables in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualhost, apache2

Whenever I run `sudo apache2 -S` on my server it throws the following error:

```
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303217 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303414 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303503 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303577 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.303655 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Mar 04 16:17:22.306324 2018] [core:warn] [pid 31405:tid 140656836052864] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

I've tried several things but it keeps giving me these errors... I made some adjustments to `apache2.conf` but that ended up not working so I reverted my changes, tried downloading the default `ennvar`didn't work

My `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file looks like this:

```
            # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
            # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
            # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
            # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
            # hints.
            #
            #
            # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
            # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
            # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
            # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
            # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
            # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
            # possible.

            # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
            # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
            #
            #   /etc/apache2/
            #   |-- apache2.conf
            #   |   `--  ports.conf
            #   |-- mods-enabled
            #   |   |-- *.load
            #   |   `-- *.conf
            #   |-- conf-enabled
            #   |   `-- *.conf
            #   `-- sites-enabled
            #       `-- *.conf
            #
            #
            # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
            #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
            #   web server.
            #
            # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
            #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
            #   customized anytime.
            #
            # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
            #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
            #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
            #   respectively.
            #
            #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
            #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
            #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
            #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
            #
            # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
            #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
            #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
            #   work with the default configuration.


            # Global configuration
            #

            #
            # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
            # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
            #
            # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
            # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
            # at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
            # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
            #
            # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
            #
            ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

            #
            # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
            #
            Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

            #
            # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
            # identification number when it starts.
            # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
            #
            PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

            #
            # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
            #
            Timeout 300

            #
            # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
            # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
            #
            KeepAlive On

            #
            # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
            # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
            # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
            #
            MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

            #
            # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
            # same client on the same connection.
            #
            KeepAliveTimeout 5


            # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
            User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
            Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

            #
            # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
            # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
            # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
            # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
            # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
            # nameserver.
            #
            HostnameLookups Off

            # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
            # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
            # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
            # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
            # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
            #
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

            #
            # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
            # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
            # error, crit, alert, emerg.
            # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
            # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
            #
            LogLevel warn

            # Include module configuration:
            IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
            IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

            # Include list of ports to listen on
            Include ports.conf


            # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
            # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
            # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
            # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
            # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
            # access here, or in any related virtual host.
            <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all denied
            </Directory>

            <Directory /usr/share>
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
            </Directory>

            <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
            </Directory>

            #<Directory /srv/>
            #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            #   AllowOverride None
            #   Require all granted
                IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
            #</Directory>




            # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
            # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
            # directive.
            #
            AccessFileName .htaccess

            #
            # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
            # viewed by Web clients.
            #
            <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
                Require all denied
            </FilesMatch>


            #
            # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
            # a CustomLog directive.
            #
            # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
            # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
            # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
            # requests.
            #
            # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
            # Use mod_remoteip instead.
            #
            LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
            LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
            LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

            # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
            # see README.Debian for details.

            # Include generic snippets of statements
            IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

            # Include the virtual host configurations:
            IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

            # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

What could be the problem, what am I missing?

This post is a continuation of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085166/virtualhost-apache-on-ubuntu-server-not-working

**EDIT**

I added this to my `envvars` file:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

This fixed once error but now I still get these errors:

```
    [Mon Mar 05 17:52:45.978727 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9150] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
    [Mon Mar 05 17:52:45.978953 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9150] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
    [Mon Mar 05 17:52:45.979024 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9150] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
    [Mon Mar 05 17:52:45.979109 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9150] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
    [Mon Mar 05 17:52:45.982417 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9150:tid 140490114955136] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
    [Mon Mar 05 17:52:45.982709 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9150:tid 140490114955136] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
    [Mon Mar 05 17:52:45.982771 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9150:tid 140490114955136] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
    AH00543: apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

Comment: Greetings! Just suggestion - You have a problem with the first variable in the config. Maybe some syntax troubles here. Try to comment first directive `# ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"` and restart Apache2 `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: I changed it but I am still getting the error...

Comment: Usually, Apache works without adding vars in the user environment. Do You have original config? If not - try to get from the archive from the official site and use it. It is good practice make a copy of original config file before changs: `cp apache2.conf apache2.conf_orig`

Comment: I reinstalled it multiple times and havent changed a thing in the config so it is the original config @SergeySerov

Comment: `journalctl -xe` and `systemctl status apache2.service` will show You additional information for debugging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache2 config variable is not defined](https://serverfault.com/questions/558283/apache2-config-variable-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Apache is complaining that the environment variables that are usually defined in `/etc/apache2/envvars` aren't defined. The startup script for `apache2` runs that file if it's present, to set `APACHE_LOCK_DIR` and friends.

If your file in `/etc/apache2` is really named `envvar` and not `envvars`, then that's your problem.

Comment: `root@vps520749:~# ls /etc/apache2
000-default.conf  conf-enabled  mods-available  sites-available
apache2.conf      envvars       mods-enabled    sites-enabled
conf-available    magic         ports.conf` so the folder is called `envvars`

Comment: what else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set those variables in the start script as part of the users env. Same with Systemd.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Whats the start script?

Comment: It’s the thing you use to start Apache

Comment: I start Apache with `sudo service apache2 start` that's correct right? Or should I use something else

Comment: Yes, then your start script is /etc/init.d/apache2

Comment: so should I change something in that file?

Comment: @LeviVerkerk This file `/etc/init.d/apache2` must stay unchanged! :) `sudo service apache2 start` is ok, all changes only in configs here: `/etc/apache2/*` and make a copy of original configs for reverting in fault case.