# In CENTOS 7 how to solve "Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined" Apache error?

Tags: centos7, apache2

I have the same error as described on [Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/558283/apache2-config-variable-is-not-defined) but none of the solutions are directly use-able on the file/directories in httpd of **CentOS**. The two solutions were to source the `/etc/apache2/envvars` file which I don't casually see in etc/httpd, and start using the apache script which will create the env variables but `apachectl start` still gave the error from `configtest`:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl configtest
[Mon Jun 04 23:38:14.248931 2018] [core:warn] [pid 81293] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Jun 04 23:38:14.249056 2018] [core:warn] [pid 81293] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
Syntax OK
```